# How to do partial state updates with hooks in React/TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to convert a component with state from class-based to functional, my state class looks like this:

```
class Person {
    name:string = ""
    email:string = ""
}
```

my class component looks like this:

```
class Component1 extends React.Component<{}, Person> {
    state: Person = new Person();
    foo() {
        this.setState ({name:"me"});
    }
}
```

you can see the setState call is only updating one property of the state. converting it to a functional component looks like this:

```
function Component() {
    const [state, setState] = useState(new Person())
    function foo() {
        setState({name:"me"})
    }
}
```

but I get a compilation error on the setState call

```
Argument of type '{ name: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<Person>'.
  Property 'email' is missing in type '{ name: string; }' but required in type 'Person'.
```

Obviously the problem goes away if I use `setState({...state, name:"me"})` but I don't want to have to do that if this is just a glitch in the TypeScript bindings.

Comment: I think you have misunderstanding between this.setState and setState, in class component calling this.setState() with object means, keys you're defining will get updated rest keys will stay as they so internally react is doing this.setState({ ...oldState, ...newObj }) but in functional component setState will replace the value of state with new one so if you want to maintain keys you've to do setState({ ...oldState, name: "me" })

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [React Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate) have a note on this:

> Note
>
> Unlike the setState method found in class components, useState does
>   not automatically merge update objects. You can replicate this
>   behavior by combining the function updater form with object spread
>   syntax:
>
> setState(prevState => {
>     // Object.assign would also work
>     return {...prevState, ...updatedValues};
>   });
>
> Another option is useReducer,
>   which is more suited for managing state objects that contain multiple
>   sub-values.

So your options are to either:

1. Use spread syntax like above.
2. Split your person state into two separate `useState`s.
3. Use useReducer. This will still require spreading pervious state into the return value though.

Comment: Thanks - it had never occurred to me you could call useState more than once

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to use multiple setState's and want to have the api similar to `this.setState`

You could repurpose `useReducer` like this:

```
  const [state, setState] = useReducer(
    (prevState, payload) => ({ ...prevState, ...payload }),
   {}
  );
  
  // Now you can do 

  setState({ a: "hello" })
  // or
  setState({ b:"world" })
```